# Auto play video when visible using Jwplayer

Tags: java, android

I want my videos to autoplay just like facebook and instagram
I'm using jwplayer

my code :

```
  PlaylistItem item = new PlaylistItem.Builder()
            .file("http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4")
            .description("Some really great content")
            .title("Video Sample")
            .build();
    PlayerConfig playerConfig = new PlayerConfig.Builder()
            .logoFile("jw_logo.png")
            .autostart(true)
            .repeat(false)
            .build();

    JWPlayerView playerView = new JWPlayerView(context, playerConfig);
    ViewGroup jwPlayerViewContainer = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.playerView1);
    jwPlayerViewContainer.addView(playerView);
    playerView.load(item);

    JWPlayerView playerView2 = new JWPlayerView(context, playerConfig);
    ViewGroup jwPlayerViewContainer2 = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.playerView4);
    jwPlayerViewContainer2.addView(playerView2);
    playerView2.load(item);
```

Comment: ... and? What doesn't work? What did you try?

Comment: In order to help others understand your issue, please post a sample of the outputs of any logs (e.g. LogCat) or something to demonstrate a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your problem.

Comment: @edGeorge My apologies, I'm an Amateur